# How to separate the sentence into words?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

split the sentence into words with out using "`componentsSeparatedByString`:"

my word is "This is a well known simple"

I wrote like this `separtedWord=[noteTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];`
but I want with out using `componentsSeparatedByString`.please help me

Comment: why you don't want to use componentsSeparatedByString ?

Comment: any specific reason for not using componentsSeparatedByString?

Comment: in my task ask like that please tell me how to do?

Comment: @iOS_Ramesh are you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @iOS_Ramesh is any of our answers helpful? If so, please accept helpful answer. Otherwise let us now what extra you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrote following logic. Created two properties like this :

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *strings;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *tempString;
```

Wrote business logic like this :

```
NSString *sampleString = @"This is a well known simple";
self.tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
self.strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for( int i = 0; i < sampleString.length; i++ )
{
    unichar currentChar = [sampleString characterAtIndex:i];
    NSString *character = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&currentChar length:1];

    if( currentChar != ' ' )
    {
        [self.tempString appendString:character];

        if( i == sampleString.length - 1 )
        {
            [self addString:self.tempString];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self addString:self.tempString];
        [self.tempString setString:@""];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Array Of String = %@",self.strings);

- (void)addString:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.strings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:string]];
}
```

2014-07-24 15:23:22.306 ViemoPlayer[1834:70b] Array Of String = (
    This,
    is,
    a,
    well,
    known,
    simple
)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So like `[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` then?

Comment: If you use [sampleString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "], it will directly return the array of strings.

Comment: The word `"simple"` is missing from the output and you can do a quicker comparison with `if (currrentChar != ' ') { ... }` rather than creating `NSString *character`.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for pointing that "simple" is missing from output. Also thanks for suggesting quicker comparison. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the NSString into a char array.
Loop through the array and an if statement inside, and keep appending the charecters inside the charArray into a local NSMutableString using

```
for(int i =0;i<[myCharArray count];i++){
 NSMutableString *teststring;
[teststring appendString:[myCharArray objectAtIndex : i]];

if([myCharArray objectAtIndex] == " "){
     NSLog(teststring);
     teststring = @""; //emptying the testString when we get a space
 }
}
```

That should do it

Comment: An array of what objects?

Comment: An array of charecters that you are taking from the String you mentioned earlier

Comment: How does `[myCharArray objectAtIndex] == " "` even compile, let alone work, then?